# Is it possible to make Vim auto-save files?

Tags: save, crash-recovery

Some word processors and text editors auto-save the files we're editing from time to time, which is very convenient for surviving from nasty crashes, etc.

Is there a way to make Vim auto-save our files after a specific interval?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There isn't a builtin option, although `:help 'autosave'` (in todo.txt) refers to a description of what such an option could do.

One possible way to implement this is to use the `CursorHold` autocommand event.  This event is triggered when the user hasn't pressed a key for `'updatetime'` milliseconds.

```
autocmd CursorHold * update
```

The `:update` command only saves the buffer if it is modified.  If you also wanted this to happen while insert mode is active, `CursorHoldI` could be added to the event list.

```
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * update
```

Another alternative is the `'autowrite'` option, which will save the buffer before executing an external command (useful for saving before running `:make`) or switching to a different buffer.

Comment: How can you notice if it is working?

Comment: @nilon It should print to the status bar that it's saved, just as if you have pressed :w yourself.

Comment: how much is 'updatetime' milliseconds? , and how I can edit that?

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi updatetime is an option. `:help 'updatetime'` to learn more about it

Comment: Just to extend the answer: you can stop receiving the message in the status bar using: `autocmd CursorHold * silent update`.

Answer (score 12):

Vim does have an auto-save feature, but it saves it to the "recovery" file.

When you edit a document, e.g. `MyFile.txt` vim will create the revovery file `.MyFile.txt.swp`. If your system were to crash, or your session were to die, then you can reconnect, and recover from essentially where you left off, by typing:

```
vim -r MyFile.txt
```

This will open the file for editing, and recover the last changes you made to it.

You can then save the recovered version the normal way `:w`.

Unfortunately, when you exit vim, it will leave the `.MyFile.txt.swp` around, and you need to remove it manually:

```
rm .MyFile.txt.swp
```

See ["Recovery" Man page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#recovery)
Also [Chapter 11](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_11.html)

Comment: When you exit Vim properly (i.e. with `:wq` or `:q!` or `ZZ` or etc.), swap files should automatically be removed.

Comment: @Doorknob not when you exit after a recovery... ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I made a plugin [vim-autosave](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-autosave) which uses Vim 8 feature of Timers to periodically save your buffers.

Comment: Woah, Vim 8 plugins coming out already. Looks great, Christian!

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  This looks promising.  I wonder if the plugin supports new/unsaved files. I can't find the answer in the plugin documentation.  My computer decided to restart last night and I had several quick notes on new buffers.  Vim didn't create or conserve swp files.

Comment: No, currently, it does not support new/unsaved files. If you want that, go ahead and create a whishlish issue.

Answer (score 3):

I make my Vim save everything every time focus is lost.

```
autocmd FocusLost <your-patterns-here> silent! wall
```

My patterns are pretty long and I use them in several autocmds but for completeness this is what it looks like:

```
if exists(':keeppatterns')
    let s:keeppatterns = 'keeppatterns '
else
    let s:keeppatterns = ''
endif

augroup AutoSaveGroup
    " :help file-pattern has some info,
    " but some of it is is buried in the PATTERNS section of usr_40.txt
    let s:autoPattern = "*.{c,h,[ch]pp,[acjt]s,inl,cg,cgfx,fx,py,bat,cmd,jam,vim,yml,yaml,vsprops,erb,rb,html,htm},SCons*,*vimrc"

    autocmd!
    execute "autocmd FocusLost"     s:autoPattern   "silent! wall"
    execute "autocmd BufWritePre"   s:autoPattern   s:keeppatterns . 'call FixFormatting(expand("<afile>"))'

    execute "autocmd FileChangedRO" s:autoPattern "silent !p4 edit %:p"
    execute "autocmd FileChangedRO" s:autoPattern "write!"

    autocmd FocusLost   *.txt   silent! wall
augroup END
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, vim has a swap file (.swp) that will be created where ever your original file is, but in your .vimrc file, you can set the .swp directory.

You'll need to create the directory with `mkdir` and then set your .vimrc to that location.

```
set backup " make backup files
set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

The [vim-workspace](https://github.com/thaerkh/vim-workspace) plugin has a fairly customizable auto-save feature that may suit your needs. By default, it enables autosave when in a workspace session (its main feature), but you can set it to always autosave if that's all you're looking for (`let g:workspace_autosave_always = 1`).

Answer (score 2):

Try to saves the buffer whenever text is changed:

```
autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent write
```

This works for me.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387138/4217744)

Comment: I also prefer `TextChanged` ("After a change was made to the text in the current buffer in Normal mode.") over `CursorHold` ("When the user doesn't press a key for the time specified with 'updatetime'"). I would be curious to understand the advantages of one or the other method. `TextChanged` feels more responsive, as I don't have to wait for the update time delay, and can close the file immediately after an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Put this on your vimrc:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => vim-autosave 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Save on lost focus/exit 
autocmd FocusLost,VimLeavePre * silent! w

" Also, save once per minute if there are changes
let g:autosave_seconds = 60 
au BufRead,BufNewFile * let b:start_time=localtime()
au CursorHold * silent! call UpdateFile()
function! UpdateFile()
  if ((localtime() - b:start_time) >= g:autosave_seconds)
    update
    let b:start_time=localtime()
  endif
endfunction
au BufWritePre * let b:start_time=localtime()
```

[Source](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Auto-save_current_buffer_periodically)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would be stronger with some explanation

Comment: This code will save your buffers on lost focus/exit. It also, save once per minute, if there are changes. You can configure the autosave interval by editing the constant 'autosave_seconds'.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add more information

Answer (score 0):

An indirect way to achieve autobackup is to enable `set undofile`. Every change of an opened file is saved there, multiple undo levels, even after a file is closed and vim exited. I consider it very practical, better than autosave.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but it is but unfortunately not built in to Vim itself. You can use an autocommand that calls a function to autosave the file:

```
" auto save file when it is modified
augroup auto_save
  autocmd!
  " call save function
  autocmd BufModifiedSet * call AutoSave()
augroup end

" save function that is called when buffer is modified
function AutoSave()
  if (bufname() != "" && &buftype == "" && &filetype != "" && &readonly == 0)
    silent write
  " prevent empty, readonly, etc... buffers from being saved
  else
  endif
endfunction
```