# Close buffer in the other instance

Tags: neovim, buffers

When a file is being opened neovim warns that swap file already exists, at which point you can't safely open a file without first closing it in the other instance.

I frequently have many projects open in different instances, which sometimes use shared files.
It is difficult to find which instance is using the file I want to open (especially if refactoring tools open them in the background).

Is it possible to close the buffer in the other instance from the active one?

Comment: Maybe you'll want to just disable swapfiles: `:h noswapfile`

Comment: What is the downside of disabling them?

Comment: Well, you won't have a backup if vim crashes and you have unsaved changes. You could lose changes made in another instance, too. That's when `autowrite` comes to help. There're others, more reliable ways to autosave files (check [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-it-possible-to-make-vim-auto-save-files)). Then, you can `autoread` so you'll load changes made to your files.

Comment: The swapfile is your protection from parallel editing the same file in multiple instances. Also it is useful to recover after a crash. In short: Think twice before disabling!  Read `:h 'swapfile' and ':h swap-file'.

Comment: One might be able to reuse the [editexisting plugin](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/editexisting/plugin/editexisting.vim), but instead of opening the existing instance, close the buffer there. Note, this relies on `remote_expr()` functions, thus does not work for Neovim (who patched that out I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is about saving files, here's how I do it.

### Vim files out of my way

```
if exists('$SUDO_USER')  " no files for root user
    set noswapfile
    set nobackup
    set nowritebackup
    set noundofile
    set viminfo=
else                     " I created a tmp folder
    set backupdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/backup//
    set directory=$HOME/.vim/tmp/swap//
    set undodir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/undo//
    set viewdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/view//
    set viminfo+=n$HOME/.vim/tmp/viminfo
endif
```

The `//` is to avoid conflicts: it will create a file based on the path, so 2 files named the same can't conflict here.

### Auto write AND read

```
set autoread
set autowriteall
```

### Save when focus is lost, load when focus is gained

A complement for `autowriteall` and `autoread`.

```
augroup FocusAutoReadWrite
    au!
    au FocusGained,BufEnter * :silent! !
    au FocusLost,WinLeave * :silent! w
augroup end
```

GTK vim and Neovim handle it by default (`:h :FocusGained`).

In regular terminal vim, a compatible terminal is needed to get focus events. I use it with `tmux` and [this extension](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events).

Sorry for telling you to disable your swap files. I thought that's what I do, but I don't. And I don't think you should do it when you can set them up properly...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use:

```
set noswapfile
set autowriteall
```

All of my important work is under git, so recovery is not a problem and while multiple-edits might be a problem, I guess I will just have to be careful.