# How do you open text files exclusively for writing so that other applications cant access it at that time?

Tags: terminal

How can I restrict my other terminals from accessing one of my already opened file (within `vim`)? 
Sometimes I forget which one of my terminals has that particular file already opened and again open it in a new different `GNOME terminal`. What I would like to have is, vim would warn me or simply refuse to open it, because its already openned in another GNOME terminal. I found an `-e` switch, but it opens a blank window and says:

`Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.` which I dont know what purpose.
Any ideas how can I tell vim to open it and do not let any other applications anyway open it until I'm done finish closing it?

Comment: Vim *does* warn you (by default) when you open a file in two different instances. If it does not, it means your config prevents this behaviour. You might want to read [this thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25130/close-buffer-in-the-other-instance/25234#25234) which is about a similar question.

Comment: By default, if you open a file in two vim instances, you get a message about swapfiles and have to choose how to proceed. Are you opening all files in vim? Do you have swapfiles disabled?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Yap. Swapfiles disabled

Comment: Then you've disabled vim's only mechanism to detect this situation... Personally, I recommend not disabling them /shrug

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Yep. it leaves lots of .swp files imho

Comment: But it cleans them up when you exit vim (unless vim crashes or is exited "abnormally" (e.g., `kill`...)). You can also set `directory` to a spot where you want all the swap files to go, if you don't like them in the current directory (e.g., `set directory ^=~/.swap//`)

Comment: If having swapfiles besides your files is what bothers you, you can have them  pop in a specific folder. You could also detect when a file is read and written and have vim to "refresh" it automatically.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Yep. those .swp files surviving crash+force_kill. I am open opening all my files in vim :/ . lots of .swp files solution should be `set directory ^=~/.swap//`. Lesson learned (y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a slight frame challenge, make sure you use swapfiles. This is how vim detects simultaneous edits.

If you think the “clutter” your directories, consider doing

```
set directory^=~/.swap//
```

And `mkdir ~/.swap` in a shell. Then all your swap files are in this one directory.